# Proper way to replace string with callback

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on implementation of a CMS and want to include functionality similar to how word press uses short codes, but I am having trouble replacing the "shortcode" with the function callback.

I'm using the below regex to find all "shortcodes" in the code and it works, I just can't figure out how to go about replacing it with function callbacks.

Regex: /[([^]]*)]/

What I have so far(not working)

```
function runShortcodes($input){
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/\[([^\]]*)\]/', function ($matches)
                {
                $function = $matches[1];
                ob_start();
                $function();
                $return = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                return $return;
                }, $input
        );
    }
function event(){
        return 'it worked';
    }
echo runShortcodes('test [event]');
```

Right now i'm just trying to replace the [event] with the return data of the event function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using output buffering to capture the value from the short code function, you will need to actually output something from the `event()` function...

```
function event(){
    return 'it worked';
}
```

just passes the value back, try...

```
function event(){
    echo 'it worked';
}
```

Or remove the output buffering and just return the value from the short code...

```
function runShortcodes($input){
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\[([^\]]*)\]/', function ($matches)
        {
            $function = $matches[1];
            return $function();
    }, $input
    );
}
function event(){
    return 'it worked';
}
echo runShortcodes('test [event]');
```